# Beginner scheme :Consumes two lists and and produces a list of all members in list1 that are not in list2

Tags: scheme, racket

For example:

```
(check-expect(2-list empty (list 3 4)) empty）
(check-expect(process-2-lists (list "nice" 'blue) empty)(list "nice" 'blue))
(check-expect(process-2-lists (list "nice" 'blue 5 10 5 'blue 5) (list "nice" 5 5 'red "wow")) (list 'blue 10 'blue))
```

Comment: I made cond statement with list1 as empty and then list 2 as empty but then i get stuck on when it's time that both have variables in them

Comment: @JamesLalonde are you posting all of your homework here today? At least copy the code you've written so far in the question, show some effort!

Comment: I posted the code to both the questions and all they needed were some modifications. The only one I didn't post was this one because I just have problem with one of the 3 possible conds. =(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll give you some hints, as usual I expect people to solve their own homework. It's the only way to learn!

```
(define (process-2-lists l1 l2)
  (cond (<???>       ; if the first list is empty
         <???>)      ; then we return the empty list
        (<???>       ; if the first element in l1 is not in l2 (*)
         (cons <???> ; then we add it to the result using cons
           (process-2-lists <???> l2))) ; and advance the recursion
        (else                           ; otherwise
         (process-2-lists <???> l2))))  ; advance the recursion adding nothing
```

Notice that we only need to traverse one of the lists, we need the other one for checking against it. The key line here is the one marked with `(*)`. How are we going to do this? well you *could* write your own helper procedure for testing membership of an element in another list, but if you take a look at the [documentation](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html) you'll find just what you need.

Comment: Thank you so much for all your help! For all of my questions. You're template really helps as well with the tips. Do you have any tips on coming up with templates on my own?

Comment: My pleasure. And sure, take a look at either The Little Schemer or how to Design Programs, they show you how to write solutions for this kinds of problems, with their own kind of "templates" or "recipes"

Answer (score 0):

filter item in list b.

```
(filter
  (lambda (item)
    (not (member item b)))
  a)
```